# Example of nef and big, not ample

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

What would be a common, simple example of a nef and big divisor that is not ample?

Are there any common, less simple examples? Are there any common strategies for finding examples?

Comment: Here's an "uncommon, less simple" example. Take a pencil of cubics in $\mathbb{P}^2$. Then this has a base locus consisting of $9$ points. Blow up those $9$ points to get a morphism $X\rightarrow\mathbb{P}^1$. Then it is known that $-K_X$ is nef but not ample. Edit: I realized after writing this comment that this question is old so pardon me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The easiest way to get examples is to observe that nefness and bigness are preserved under pullbacks via birational morphisms, but ampleness isn't.

So let $Y$ be normal and let $f: X \to Y$ be any birational morphism that is not an isomorphism. If $A$ is an ample divisor on $Y$, then $f^*A$ is nef and big but not ample.

The simplest such example would be $f: X \to \mathbf P^2$ the blowup of a point, and $H$ a line in $\mathbf P^2$. Then $f^*H$ is nef and big, but it has degree 0 on the exceptional divisor, so it isn't ample.

Examples obtained in this way all have a special property: the nef and big divisor $f^*A$ we obtain is always *semi-ample*, meaning that some multiple of it is basepoint-free (a.k.a. globally generated). But in general a nef and big divisor need not be semi-ample. Examples of this kind are more subtle: see Section 2.3 of *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry I* by Lazarsfeld for a nice exposition.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer. Do you happen to be aware of any particularities in positive characteristic?

Comment: You can try this paper to get some idea of the positive characteristic case: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~totaro/papers/public_html/moving.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Using the implications for any rank vector bundles
\begin{equation}
\text{ample}\iff\text{positive}\Rightarrow\text{semi-positive};
\end{equation}
in [D.P.S. example 1.7](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/dps1.pdf), the authors constructed a nef rank $2$ vector bundle $E$ over an elliptic curve $\Gamma$ which is not semi-positive, so it is not an ample vector bundle.

To be exact, $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}(1)=L$ is a nef line bundle over the ruled surface $\mathbb{P}(E)=X$; by [D.P. theorem 4.3](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/kahlercone.pdf) $\displaystyle\int_Xc_1(L)^2>0$, by [D. J.-P. corollary 6.19](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/analmeth_book.pdf) $L$ is also a big line bundle; but $L$ is not a semi-positive line bundle, that is $L$ is not an ample line bundle.

For a recap of these results, see [D. J.-P. sections 6 and 18](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Edemailly/manuscripts/analmeth_book.pdf).

*Post Scriptum*

1. D.P.S. means J.-P. Demailly, T. Peternell, M. Schneider - *Compact complex manifolds with numerically effective tangent bundles*, J. Alg. Geom. **3** (1994) 295-345
2. D.P. means J.-P. Demailly, M. Păun - *Numerical characterization of the Kähler cone of a compact Kähler manifold*, Annals of Math. **159** (2004) 1247-1274
3. D.J.-P. means J.-P. Demailly - *Analytic Methods in Algebraic Geometry* (2010) Higher Education Press, Surveys of Modern Mathematics, Vol. 1